# Client authentication (certificat + private key) using WinInet

Tags: c++, ssl, winapi, https, wininet

- This is an evolution of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258304/client-authentication-certificat-private-key-using-winhttp), which was about WinHttp.
- I hope this is the right way to do this...

I'm trying to communicate in https with a server using WinInet (from the Win32 API).

Here is a very minimalist code :

```
HINTERNET ses = InternetOpen("test",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0) ;
HINTERNET con = InternetOpenUrl( ses,"https://stackoverflow.com",NULL,0,0,0 ) ;
DWORD read ;
char  str [3000] ;
InternetReadFile( con,reinterpret_cast<void*>( str ),sizeof( str )-1,&read ) ;
str[read] = 0 ;
cout << &str[0] ;
InternetCloseHandle( con ) ;
InternetCloseHandle( ses ) ;
```

As long as I communicate with a "classic" https server, like stackoverflow.com, everything goes well. The problem is when I try to communicate with a server that requests an authentication of the client.

I have 3 .pem files : a certificate and a private key for my client, and a root certificate that authenticates my client certificate (i.e. a certificate chain of length 2).

For information, I can connect my server using this cULR command line :

`curl https://my.server --cert Client_cert.pem --key Client_key.pem --cacert Root_cert.pem`

**This is the proof that it's possible!**

Reading the WinInet documentation, I found a page named "[Handling Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/WinInet/handling-authentication)", but it's all about username:password, and there's nothing about certificate.

I found out that I have to use the Crypt32 library : I have to create a certificate context with `CertCreateCertificateContext` and then insert it in a certificat store, and then use that store for my connection...
Well, I must admit that I would be glad to find a good tutorial or some code sample !
By the way, I don't have a piece of clue about how to insert my private key into that stuff...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your certificate to WinInet using [INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/WinInet/option-flags) with a call to [InternetSetOption()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetoptiona):

> INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT
>
> 84
>
> This flag is not supported by InternetQueryOption. The lpBuffer
>   parameter must be a pointer to a CERT_CONTEXT structure and not a
>   pointer to a CERT_CONTEXT pointer. If an application receives
>   ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED, it must call InternetErrorDlg
>   or use InternetSetOption to supply a certificate before retrying the
>   request. CertDuplicateCertificateContext is then called so that the
>   certificate context passed can be independently released by the
>   application.

So, for example:

```
InternetSetOption(hI,INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT,(void*)cert,sizeof(CERT_CONTEXT));
```

Btw, curl calls are not good examples because curl uses [libcurl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) which uses OpenSSL.

Comment: Thx, I have already read that page... The tricky part is that I have to build a CERT_CONTEXT that contains a handle to a certificate store : do I have to build it first ? And what about the client's private key ? And how do I check the certificate chain ? Do I have to do it myself ?

Comment: It depends where you have this certificate. Is it in a PFX file? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-pfximportcertstore - PFXImportStore. Then you can CertEnumCertificatesInStore to loop through all the certificates. The private key is automatically included when it is needed when it exists (you may be prompted with a PIN request, for example). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key

Comment: My 2 certificate + 1 private key are stored in .pem files. And my code is supposed to run silently, so a PIN request is not possible...

Comment: If you have the private key and the public key, you save it in a PFX with the pvk2pfx tool and then import it and use it with the functions I said. Also, you need one certificate. The chain, if any, will be validated from the server, not you. If this is not a key signed by a certificate authority that your server knows, the chain you would provide is useless anyway. If it's your own organization, then the server will be already aware of the root certificate.

Comment: Thank you Michael ! Finally I managed to build a PFX from my 2 certificates + private key. I import it using `PFXImportCertStore`, but now that I have a brand new `HCERTSTORE`, I can't figure out how to _pass_ it to my https connection... It's not using `InternetSetOption`... I don't see any Internet or Http function that takes a `HCERTSTORE` as parameter.

Comment: The certificate store has your certificates, you can find them with [CertEnumCertificatesInStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certenumcertificatesinstore)